# Combining two tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, intersection

I have two polygon shapefiles,each with different data.  One has US counties  It's fields are long, Lat, area_meters, perimeter, state, and county name.

The other shapefile shows wilderness boundaries and has State.  My goal is to figure out every county that these wilderness areas are in.  Some do encompass two or more counties.  I was thinking of doing a table join based on state but that does not seem to work.  It puts each record in only one county.

When I display the counties shapefile and boundary shapefile they show nicely in ArcMap and I could do it manually but their are a lot.

Wanted to know if way to do it with ArcMap or FME?

Any thoughts?

Comment: The [Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/) or [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) tools might also help with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Intersect (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool. The results should be what you are looking for.